# How do I set box layout for a nameless JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager, boxlayout

Ok I am trying to setLayout as BoxLayout for a nameless jFrame, what do I put in place instead of 'WhatDoIPutHere?'

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class InterestCalculator extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        InterestCalculator comp = new InterestCalculator();
        comp.FrameHandler();
    }

    public void FrameHandler() {

        setTitle("Template");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(WhatDoIPutHere?, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is a `CONSTANT_ALL_UPPER`) and use it consistently.

Comment: Use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Create a `JPanel`
- Set the box layout to the panel
- Add the panel to the frame.

As an aside, don't extend `JFrame` unless changing existing functionality or adding new functionality.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm very new to the GUI stuff.

Comment: *"How do I do that?"*  Try doing it.  If you experience a problem, get back to us with an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28307099/edit)..